# xcode - How can I add a Toolbar to a UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios8, uitoolbar

I have a little problem. I wanna add a Toolbar in the button of my UITableViewController, but it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Did the answer help?  Are you still having issues using a toolbar with your tableViewController?

Answer (score 1):

If your `UITableViewController` is embedded in `UINavigationController`, the navigation controller comes with a toolbar.  You wouldn't need to add your own.

The navigation controller's toolbar is hidden by default.  You can enable it by:

- Checking the **Shows toolbar** option in the navigation controller Interface Builder attribute inspector pane, or
- Setting the toolbar visibility in code:

  ```
  [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
  ```

Enabling the toolbar in Storyboard has the advantage of letting you drag and drop items onto it using Interface Builder.  You can also add toolbar items in code, by calling `setToolbarItems:`