# Adding a Toolbar to a UITableViewController Using Swift

Tags: swift, ios8.3

I wish to add a toolbar to the bottom of a tableview. In this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30432729/xcode-how-can-i-add-a-toolbar-to-a-uitableviewcontroller) I learned that "If your UITableViewController is embedded in UINavigationController, the navigation controller comes with a toolbar. You wouldn't need to add your own.". The author of that post proceeds to lists the objective-c code to make it visible. Could I please be directed to a tutorial or example which demonstrates the swift code that will to the same thing? I am new to iOS apps and Xcode, learning it as I go.

Answer (score 5):

To make the toolbar visible, simply use this function in the viewDidLoad :

```
self.navigationController!.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)
```

To populate with items, you have the setToolbarItem function :

```
self.navigationController!.setToolbarItems(<toolbarItems: [AnyObject]?>, animated: <Bool>)
```

Here is the link for the
[UINavigationController class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/)

Comment: This works but I cant seem to add any buttons to the toolbar that show up.  Any thoughts?